# Can i add passsync for 2 deferent FreeIPA

Tags: active-directory, password, freeipa

I have 2 IPA server & both have deferent machines registered with it. Now i able to configure user sync agreement with Active Directory from both the IPA & i am able to see all AD users in both IPA. 
Now i have to configure passsync to sync the password. i have installed passsync.msi in AD, but here i have option to configure only one IPA.

reference: `https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/8.2/html/Installation_Guide/Install_the_Password_Sync_Service.html`

Answer (score 0):

Only a single server can be configured as a target of passsync. This is how the code in passsync module is written. Since all IPA replicas will get content via replication from each other, only a single server would be the originator of that content. If passsync would have synchronized to multiple servers, this would have caused a conflict because then two or more IPA replicas would be distributing the exact same change to other nodes.

Comment: Some added detail and  a source citation for your assertion might improve your answer

Comment: You can read documentation: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Directory_Server/9.0/html/Administration_Guide/Windows_Sync-Configuring_Windows_Sync.html, it shows screenshots of how passsync is configured, there is no way to enter more than one server there. Also updated my answer with more details on why it is so.